# ProgressBar Visibilty doesn't change

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, progress-bar

I want that progress bar will appear then login progress will start, so i code these for click event;

```
private void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    customClasses.LogIn logIn = new customClasses.LogIn(txtLoginUsername.Text, pswdLoginPassword.Password, this);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => otherMethods.enableProgressBar(prgLoginLoading)));
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => logIn.SignIn()));
}
```

This is inside of enableProgressBar

```
public static void enableProgressBar(ProgressBar bar)
{
    bar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

So this is my progressbar XAML

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="prgLoginLoading" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="14" IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

But it didn't work when i debug code ProgressBar Visibility properties is still Hidden.
How can i fix that?

Comment: What's the intention behind the `new ThreadStart(` part?

Comment: Without it i can't give any parameter

Comment: You could try using `Action` instead of `ThreadStart`, which seems a bit weird. This might also be helpful: [Dispatcher BeginInvoke Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760777/dispatcher-begininvoke-syntax).

Comment: A proper approach would be to use `IProgress` along visual states.

Answer (score 0):

Change `enableProgressBar` to below

```
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate ()
    {
          bar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }));
```

Change

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => otherMethods.enableProgressBar(prgLoginLoading)));
```

to

```
otherMethods.enableProgressBar(prgLoginLoading);
```